# Managing DbContext in WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, architecture

I've been banging my head with this for days and still can't decide on which is the correct approach.
This question is targeting `WPF` specifically since as opposed to a web-application, many posts and articles online recommends a `context` per `view-model` approach and not a `context` per `request`.
I have a `WPF MVVM` application which is using an `Entity-Framework DB first` model.
here is an example of two models used in my app (created by `EF` Designer):

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Role = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.User = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

I've narrowed my options on how to handle this to the following:

**1)** Creating a `DataAccess` class which creates and disposes of the `DbContext` on each method call:

```
public class Dal
{
    public User GetUserById(object userId)
    {
        using (var db = new DbEntities())
        {
            return db.User.Find(userId);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void RemoveUser(User userToRemove)
    {
        using (var db = new DbEntities())
        {
            db.User.Remove(userToRemove);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

which I can use in my `ViewModel` as follows:

```
public class UserManagerViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly Dal dal = new Dal();

    // models...
    //commands...
}
```

**2)** Similar to approach 1 but without the `Using` statements:

```
public class Dal : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
    public User GetUserById(object userId)
    {
        return db.User.Find(userId);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }

    public void RemoveUser(User userToRemove)
    {
        db.User.Remove(userToRemove);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The use is the same inside the `ViewModel`

**3)** Create a `repository` for each `entity`. Looks the same as the above options (also has the with or without the `using` dilemma), however every repository contains only methods related to its `entity`.
Afaik the use is the same as above inside my `ViewModel`.

**4)** Create a `Unit-Of-Work` class that will pass the appropriate`Repository` on demand:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();

    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    public IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return userRepository ?? new UsersRepository(db);
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and use it inside my `ViewModel` as follows:

```
public class UserManagerViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork();

    // models...
    //commands...
}
```

Which of the above approach (if any) is preferred in terms of in terms of data concurrency, better abstraction and layering and overall performance?
**EDIT -** Found the following paragraph in [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) :

> When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a context instance per form. This lets you use change-tracking functionality that context provides.

However, it raises the question of whether I should create a `DbContext` object in my `view-model` or is it better to have a utility class such as my `DAL` class and reference it.

Comment: EF has an excellent UoW (context) + repository (DbSet). Why create your own? Hardly ever are these extra layers helpful. They tend to lead to data-centric applications that pull business logic into the client as opposed to task-centric applications that encapsulate use cases in services that are close to the EF model. It's abstracting data vs. abstracting tasks (where abstracting means hiding persistence implementation).

Comment: See this http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your reply. Since I'm asking about `WPF MVVM` specifically, I wonder if a long lived `DbContext` should be used (a `context` per `view-model`) or should I limit the life span of my `context` as in option 1 (using the `using` :))

Comment: We've tried both approaches, and both have advantages and disadvantages. There is no one-size-fits-all solution, you just have to find out which one works best for you.
That said, we decided to go for the second approach and keep the context's life span as short as possible, because that avoids problems when you have multiple Views (think tabs or windows) with multiple ViewModels and thus multiple contexts open at the same time.

Comment: @DanielSklenitzka Thanks for your reply. would you care to explain how you made the actual db access? was it by direct query from within your commands or did you have some kind of repository that held all the queries?

Comment: Usually there's some kind of business logic layer in between that looks like your Dal and is called by the ViewModels. Each business logic operation creates a new context and does all it has to do using that context.

Comment: The truth is that you cannot define a strict way and follow it because real life scenarios are all different. I've answered the similar question recently - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26184474/731115 - if that helps..

Answer (score 2):

This is what dependency injection frameworks are designed to solve. Yes, it's yet another technology to add to your project, but once you start using DI you never look back.

The real problem here is that you're trying to make this decision in your view models when you really should be employing inversion of control and making the decision higher up. A WPF/MVVM application will want a context per-form so that changes are only submitted once a user is finished editing, and also to give the user the opportunity to cancel the changes. I know you're not using this in a web application but a well-designed architecture means you should be able to, in which case you'll want a context per request. You may want to write a console-app utility that populates the database with static data, in this case you may want a global/singleton context for performance and ease-of-use. Lastly, your unit tests also need to mock the context, probably on a per-test basis. All four of these cases should be set up in your injection framework and your view models should neither know or care about any of them.

Here's an example. I personally use Ninject, which is specifically designed for .NET. I also prefer NHibernate, although the choice of ORM is irrelevant here. I have session objects that have different scoping requirements, and this gets set up in a Ninject module that initializes my ORM classes:

```
var sessionBinding = Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var session = ctx.Kernel.Get<INHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder>()
        .GetSessionFactory()
        .OpenSession();
    return session;
});

if (this.SingleSession)
    sessionBinding.InSingletonScope();
else if (this.WebSession)
    sessionBinding.InRequestScope();
else
    sessionBinding.InScope(ScreenScope);
```

This sets up the scoping for an ISession, which is the NHibernate equivalent of your context class. My repository classes, which manage the database objects in memory, contain a reference to the session they are associated with:

```
public class RepositoryManager : IRepositoryManager
{
    [Inject]
    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    ... etc...
{
```

The [Inject] attribute tells Ninject to populate this field automatically using the scoping rules I've set up. So far this is all happening in my domain classes, but it extends to my view model layer as well. In my scoping rules I pass in an object called "ScreenScope", and while I won't go into it here it basically means that any time I ask for a session object in my ScreenViewModel, or any view models that it has as members (including their own children) the same ISession object gets automatically created and passed in to all of them. By using DI scoping I don't even have to think about it, I just declare the members with the [Inject] attribute and it happens:

```
public class ScreenViewModel
{
    [Inject] public CustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }
    [Inject] public SalesService SalesService { get; set; }
    [Inject] public BillService BillService { get; set; }
    ...etc...
}
```

These service classes all contains a RepositoryManager that has been injected, and since they're all in ScreenViewModel the ISession object will be the same, at least in my WPF build. if I switch to my MVC build they're the same for all view models created for a given request, and if I switch to a console build it uses the same ISession for everything in the entire program.

TL;DR: Use dependency injection and a scope your contexts to one-per-form.

Comment: I'm researching on DI in UI topoick, and I want to make context per event/command(in case of WPF). Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this :(      Only solution I can see, is to pass injections as method arguments, but that pretty sucks

Answer (score 0):

In my earlier usage of MVVM within WPF I was utilising an open context per VM but I quickly ran into issues with thread safety of DBContexts once applications evolved to make better use of Async.

Whilst there is a greater development overhead, I now utilise dependency injection to provide a DBContextFactory (not the DBContext itself).  I spin up a context in a using statement witihn the VM to fill observableCollections with plinq calls via EF. Another performance benefit of this method is running queries with AsNoTracking(). The annoying part is managing the reattachment of new or modified objects to the short lived context:

```
shortDBContext.Attach(myEntity).State = EntityState.Added; // or modified
await shortDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```